# Mysql order by values in array

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, usort

I want to manually sort items from a table. The background is that I have different items listed grouped on item type and then sorted by the id so the article numbers are presented as

```
Item type 1 - 4109
Item type 1 - 1342
Item type 1 - 3193
Item type 2 - 6971
Item type 2 - 0484
```

The sql string is shown below.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM '".$table."' WHERE model = '".$model."' ORDER BY item, id ASC";
```

Instead of sorting the article numbers based on id ASC I want to sort them by a defined array like

```
$sortItem1 = [1342, 4109, 3193];
$sortItem2 = [0484, 6971];
```

The items shall be listed grouped on item and the article numbers shall be sorted as the arrays $sortItem1 and $sortItem2. The result should then be

```
    Item type 1 - 1342
    Item type 1 - 4109
    Item type 1 - 3193
    Item type 2 - 0484
    Item type 2 - 6971
```

I don't think the code below is possible but I want it to be sorted like

```
ORDER BY item, $sortItem1, $sortItem2
```

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: this code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and use **prepared statements with parameters**.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to use usort instead. My idea is to save all parameters that I need like

```
    $totalItems = 0;
    $sortOrder = ['4109', '1342', '3193', '6971', '0484'];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $itemsToSort[$totalItems][0] = $row['item'];
        $itemsToSort[$totalItems][1] = $row['articleNumber'];
        $totalItems++;
    }
```

and then sort the array

```
    usort($itemsToSort, function($a, $b) use ($sortOrder){
    $valA = array_search($a[0], $sortOrder);
    $valB = array_search($b[0], $sortOrder);
    if ($valA === false)
        return -1;
    if ($valB === false)
        return 0;
    if ($valA > $valB)
        return 1;
    if ($valA < $valB)
        return -1;
    return 0;
    });
```

Then I can loop through the $itemsToSort.

This seems to work but I need to have several arrays for $sortOrder. The $sortOrder shall get its value from other arrays that can be named like $sort1, $sort2, $sort3 etc. Is it possible to copy the $sort1 array to $sortOrder?

Answer (score -1):

Use [FIELD() function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_field.asp) in ORDER clause
`ORDER BY FIELD(item, 1342, 4109, 3193, 0484, 6971)`

Comment: Is it possible to put arrays in the FIELD() instead of the numbers? I need to define the numbers in external arrays and then let the function follow that.

Comment: The MySQL does not have an array data type. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html